# Show the result of a Sum() in a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm kind of junior with ASP.net.

I have a model class named Athlete and the `AthletesController` class. I've created a separated class to develop some methods in there inside a file named DAL called `Operations`, until now everything has been working good because my methods have been working with `Athlete` class objects.

But I made a new method using Entity Framework and a linq query to get the result of the sum of all the ages of my Athlete Database. I don't know how to show this result in a view, it's just an int not an `Athlete` object. I'm calling my methods from the Controller class, and from there I add a view for each method, but I don`t have any idea of how can I display this result in a view.

Could you let me know how to do this? This method is returning just an int result as you can see.

```
public class Operations
{
    AthleteContext db = new AthleteContext();         

    public int SumByAges()
    {
        int sum = db.Athletes.Sum(p => p.Age);
        return sum;
    }
```

AthletesController:

```
public class AthletesController : Controller
{
    private Operations ope = new Operations();
    private AthleteContext db = new AthleteContext();
    public ActionResult SumByAges()
    {
        return View(ope.SumByAges());
    }
}
```

Athlete Model Class:

```
public class Athlete
{
   public int AthleteID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would expect to see a ViewModel that has a property that represents the summed ages value.  You would populate this model in your controller and pass it to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would follow @markpsmith advise and create a ViewModel for this view, however, based on what you have in the Action method this is what you would need to do

Create a view in /Views/Athletes/SumByAges.cshtml

```
@model int

<div>
    @Model
</div>
```